# Is it bad to have two identical entities?

Tags: architecture, uml, software-design

I'm in the middle of creating domain model and I need help with some entities. I have a `Sale` entity (which represents the action of selling goods to buyers) and a `Purchase` entity (which represents the act of buying goods from supplier to fill the stocks). I see the two ways of how to deal with it:

1. Create two entities `Sell` and `Purchase` and additional entities for both of them named like `Sell details` and `Purchase details` respectively, with attributes [`sell_id`/`purchase_id`, `product_id`, ..., `quantity`]. But in this case I will have two almost identical entities in my database which is obvious duplication of data.
2. The second approach I see is to create one entity `Order` with additional attribute `order_type`(and eponymous entity to store order types: `purchase` and `sell`) and `Order_details` entity so we can escape data duplication from the first approach.

Please share your experience how to deal with this case. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the "obvious" duplication of data. There is duplication of structure, but not of data.

Comment: Are you talking about UML or about database design. Your wording makes me think it's the latter. And why _identical_? Where?

Comment: @GeertBellekens Yes, you are right. It's duplication of structure. Is it bad to have two entities with the same structure?

Comment: @qwerty_so I'm talking about creating domain model, but of course later it will be implemented in the database.

Comment: If they nothin else in common apart from their structure, this doesn't have to be a bad thing. Usually though, there is a common element to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A business organization has both sales orders and purchase orders. Both object types may share quite some part of their structure, but they may also have attributes/operations/constraints that are not shared. In particular, for a business, sales orders (and the sales department) are typically more important than purchase orders (and the purchasing department). For their sales orders, they have operations like *availability check*, *delivery scheduling* and *credit limit check*, which they don't have for purchase orders.

It's normally not worthwhile to try finding an (abstract) super type of all the different types of orders of an organization (such as sales/purchase/transport/production/etc. orders) and use subtyping/inheritance for sharing some of their structural definitions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, this is what I really wanted to get! I'm going to stick with two entities and focus on sales department.